# forfiles batch command failure on tuesdays

Tags: batch-file

The below command runs on all the days but it doesn't work on tuesdays.

Error occurs from Dec'15 even though the files are available. Please provide any suggestions.

Command :

```
set dirvararchive=E:\SHAN\archive

forfiles -p %dirvararchive%\abcd\ -s -m *.zip -d -30 -c "cmd /c del @PATH"
```

> `ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.`

Regards,
Shanmugaraj

Comment: 30 Days before a Tuesday would be Sunday.  What are the odds of any files being created on a Sunday that would need to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason could be, there are no zip files in the path older than 30 days.

**-d 30** in your command will check for files older than 30 day , if you have used this command for deleting files it would run correctly for the first time and the next runs would fail with ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria. Try changing **-d 1** in your command and check the correctness of command when zip files are present older than 1 day.